# Email from PHP in Windows Azure

Tags: php, email, azure, gmail

How can send e-mail (gmail ?) with attachments from PHP in Windows Azure enviroment.

Comment: Now the first few Google results are not the best, but php mail classes are easy to find. Swiftmailer comes to mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlem/archive/2009/01/08/windows-azure-sending-smtp-emails.aspx) suggests that Windows Azure *does not come with an SMTP server*.

This means that you will need to use an available third party SMTP server to send mail.  Gmail *might* work for you.  [This seems to be Gmail's SMTP server information](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13287).

[SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) is one of the mailing libraries that is recommended frequently here.  It provides the ability to connect to authenticated SMTP servers and has comprehensive attachment support.

Comment: I got here while trying to do the same, got access to an Azure server, used PHPMailer with my gmail account but i'm having an issue, The server node appears in Switzerland, and i'm in a different country, Gmail keeps blocking the login attempts from that server, any advice?